# Problems Install Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to install Spark on Ubuntu 12.04 on a Virtual Machine.

I followed the instructions at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_spark/apache_spark_installation.htm

I have java version "1.6.0_38" and scala version "2.9.1",

I downloaded spark and moved it to the location /usr/local/spark

and on trying to start the spark shell I get the following error:

```
arj@arj-VirtualBox:/usr/local/spark/bin$ ./spark-shell 
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/launcher/Main
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.launcher.Main
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
    Could not find the main class: org.apache.spark.launcher.Main. Program will exit.
```

I am not sure what is going wrong.

Comment: Did you extract the spark tar ball. tar xvf spark-1.3.1-bin-hadoop2.6.tgz?

Comment: Yes of course. I extracted it. All the content seems to be present, not sure what is missing, cause this seems like basic default actions.

Comment: Try install java version 1.7

Comment: Is java 7 == java 1.7 ???

Answer (score 1):

Most probably I downloaded an incompatible version, so something similar.

Finally after hitting a deadend I looked for another method of installing Spark.

I came across this tutorial which explains how to build spark from its source http://blog.prabeeshk.com/blog/2014/10/31/install-apache-spark-on-ubuntu-14-dot-04/

This worked like a charm.